# Using a Custom tensorflow Model for Object Detection in browser using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow.js

Im building a website that uses the device webcam to perform real-time object detection using a custom model that I have trained and converted to js.

[This](https://github.com/Fawcett-cpu/GraphScanning/tree/main/Graph) is a github of the file structure of my model but it is saved locally for this site). My code loads the model (I think) and the webcam is loaded into the page but no detections are made.

This is the error that I am facing:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cannot compute the outputs [Identity,Identity_1,Identity_2,Identity_3,Identity_4,Identity_5,Identity_6,Identity_7] from the provided inputs []. Consider providing the following inputs: [input_tensor]. Alternatively, to avoid the dynamic ops, use model.execute() and specify the inputs [StatefulPartitionedCall/Postprocessor/BatchMultiClassNonMaxSuppression/MultiClassNonMaxSuppression/ClipToWindow/Reshape]
    at e.<anonymous> (tfjs@latest:17)
    at u (runtime.js:45)
    at Generator._invoke (runtime.js:274)
    at Generator.forEach.t.<computed> [as next] (runtime.js:97)
    at Um (tfjs@latest:17)
    at o (tfjs@latest:17)
```

This is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Lets Scan</title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/LetsScan.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cookie" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs/dist/tf.min.js">
    </script>
</head>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@latest"></script>

<body>
    <!-- Navigation Bar Code-->
    <!-- Nav Bar Code -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Graph Visuals</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
              </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="index.html">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="LetsScan.html">Lets Scan</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="ContactUs.html">Contact Us</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="AboutUs.html">About Us</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <h1 class="pageHeader">Lets Scan</h1>
    <div class="container">
        <article class="howTo">
            <h3 class="howToHeader">What To Do!</h3>
            <p>To start, hold up a graph to your camera. Ensuring that the graph is clear and completely in view</p>
        </article>
        <section id="demos" class="invisible">
            <div id="liveView" class="camView">
                <button id="webcamButton">Enable Webcam</button>
                <video id="webcam" autoplay width="640" height="480"></video>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
    <br>
    <!-- Site footer -->
    <footer class="site-footer">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                    <h6>About</h6>
                    <p class="text-justify">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus congue faucibus eros, non gravida nulla iaculis vel. Vestibulum convallis nisi enim, at ullamcorper nulla mattis quis. Curabitur congue augue in sem pretium, quis fringilla
                        odio scelerisque. Aenean a mi vehicula, sollicitudin augue in, hendrerit dui. Suspendisse eget mattis urna. Morbi purus arcu, pellentesque quis risus quis, tincidunt pulvinar augue. Phasellus suscipit lectus a suscipit ornare.
                        Praesent bibendum magna quam, non lobortis massa cursus id. Vivamus metus dolor, venenatis ac vulputate vitae, convallis non ante. Aliquam posuere in sem at finibus.</p>
                </div>



                <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
                    <h6>Quick Links</h6>
                    <ul class="footer-links">
                        <li><a href="about.php">About Us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://scanfcode.com/contribute-at-scanfcode/">Contribute</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://scanfcode.com/privacy-policy/">Privacy Policy</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://scanfcode.com/sitemap/">Sitemap</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <p class="copyright-text">Copyright &copy; 2021 Mr Callum Fawcett</p>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <ul class="social-icons">
                        <li><a class="facebook" href="facebook.com/GraphVisuals"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a class="twitter" href="twitter.com/GraphVisuals"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a class="linkedin" href="linkedin.com/GraphVisuals"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <!-- Import TensorFlow.js library -->
    <!--<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/@tensorflow/tfjs/dist/tf.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>-->
    <script type="module" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@2.0.0/dist/tf.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Load the coco-ssd model to use to recognize things in images -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow-models/coco-ssd"></script>
    <script src="/js/letsscan1.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

and this is my JavaScript -

```
const demosSection = document.getElementById('demos');

const MODEL_FILE_URL = 'models/Graph/model.json';

// Keep a reference of all the child elements we create
// so we can remove them easilly on each render.
const children = [];
const video = document.getElementById('webcam');
const liveView = document.getElementById('liveVilet');
let model = null;

// Before we can use COCO-SSD class we must wait for it to finish
// loading. Machine Learning models can be large and take a moment to
// get everything needed to run.
tf.loadGraphModel(MODEL_FILE_URL).then(function(loadedModel) {


    // If webcam supported, add event listener to button for when user
    // wants to activate it.
    if (hasGetUserMedia()) {
        const enableWebcamButton = document.getElementById('webcamButton');
        enableWebcamButton.addEventListener('click', enableCam);
    } else {
        console.warn('getUserMedia() is not supported by your browser');
    }

    demosSection.classList.remove('invisible');
});

// Check if webcam access is supported.
function hasGetUserMedia() {
    return !!(navigator.mediaDevices &&
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia);
}

// Enable the live webcam view and start classification.
function enableCam(event) {
    if (!model) {
        console.log('Wait! Model not loaded yet.')
        return;
    }

    // Hide the button.
    event.target.classList.add('removed');

    // getUsermedia parameters.
    const constraints = {
        video: true
    };

    // Activate the webcam stream.
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(function(stream) {
        video.srcObject = stream;
        video.addEventListener('loadeddata', predictWebcam);
    });
}


function predictWebcam() {
    const videoTrack = video.srcObject.getVideoTracks()[0];
    let imageCapture = new ImageCapture(videoTrack);
    imageCapture.takePhoto().then(function(img) {
        console.log(img);
        // Now let's start classifying the stream.
        model.executeAsync(img.arrayBuffer()).then(function(predictions) {
            // Remove any highlighting we did previous frame.
            for (let i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                liveView.removeChild(children[i]);
            }
            children.splice(0);

            // Now lets loop through predictions and draw them to the live view if
            // they have a high confidence score.
            for (let n = 0; n < predictions.length; n++) {
                // If we are over 66% sure we are sure we classified it right, draw it!
                if (predictions[n].score > 0.66) {
                    const p = document.createElement('p');
                    p.innerText = predictions[n].class + ' - with ' +
                        Math.round(parseFloat(predictions[n].score) * 100) +
                        '% confidence.';
                    // Draw in top left of bounding box outline.
                    p.style = 'left: ' + predictions[n].bbox[0] + 'px;' +
                        'top: ' + predictions[n].bbox[1] + 'px;' +
                        'width: ' + (predictions[n].bbox[2] - 10) + 'px;';

                    // Draw the actual bounding box.
                    const highlighter = document.createElement('div');
                    highlighter.setAttribute('class', 'highlighter');
                    highlighter.style = 'left: ' + predictions[n].bbox[0] + 'px; top: ' +
                        predictions[n].bbox[1] + 'px; width: ' +
                        predictions[n].bbox[2] + 'px; height: ' +
                        predictions[n].bbox[3] + 'px;';

                    liveView.appendChild(highlighter);
                    liveView.appendChild(p);

                    // Store drawn objects in memory so we can delete them next time around.
                    children.push(highlighter);
                    children.push(p);
                }
            }

            // Call this function again to keep predicting when the browser is ready.
            window.requestAnimationFrame(predictWebcam);
        });
    })



}
```

Can anyone help me in fixing this error and working out how to get my model to detect in real time?

Comment: Your model is not actually being passed any tensors. Somewhere between loading the camera and passing the tensors over to the model something is going wrong.

Comment: Okay, do you know where i might find the issue so I can solve it

Comment: What does `console.log(img);` output?